# Best way to create a multirouter wireless network with my current hardware

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, home-networking, wireless-bridge

I'm new to IT side of computers, and while I'm starting to grasp the basics, I keep getting into trouble when I try to utilize it in real life.

The Scenario: a 3 floor, 12 bedroom apartment. 10 laptops, 2 desktops, 2 printers (can work wireless or via ethernet). 2 dualband VDSL Netgear Vegn2610, a D-Link VEGN 6740u, and an old Netgear WPN824v3. 2 DSL lines (100mb down 5mb up - the best plans my local provider offers).

I want to set up some sort of seamless wireless network (so that no matter where you are in the house, you'll be connected to the same network, and with the multiple routers and additional network bandwidth, thinks won't bog down when everyone is online with moderate usage.

From what I've read, dsl bonding isn't an option without additional hardware. I tried just setting the routers to the same IP range (1.0.0.50 and 10.0.0.51) and name and password, but devices on one router can't communicate to those on another router, and when moving from router to router you need to manually reconnect to the new one, because the 'gateways' are different.

I'm sure there's a way to fix the gateway issue when switching, and to manage the bandwidth between routers by creating manual routes (eg. 6 devices go to router+dsl connection 1, 6devices go to router+dsl connection 2), but I can't really figure out the right way to do that and it gets even more complicated when I add the dlink router as a wireless repeater to cover the dead zones.

Thoughts, suggestions, reading materials, any and all direction is greatly appreciated. 
TIA!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bonding requires cooperation from your service provider.

Multi-WAN only requires a router that can do that. Hmm. "Dual WAN" is not actually Dual WAN on those [Vegn2610s](https://www.netgear.com/images/pdf/vegn2610.pdf), so that brief hope dies in a fizzle.

Point being, if you want one network, you need one network, with one router.

So, you may need another router that really does Multi-WAN. pfSense is one free option among many free and not-free options that can do Multi-WAN, and only costs finding a box to run it on. Set up that router, as your one router connected to both WANs, and proceed.

Then you set all your other "routers" as wireless access points (only) connected via their LAN ports (only) to the LAN that is connected to the one router with both WAN connections plugged into it. Use EXACTLY the same name and security settings for the WLAN on ALL access points.

---

As an aside, if you are managing to saturate even one 100Mbit connection with only 12 users, that's hardly "moderate use" - a perfectly reasonable approach to this would be to put in traffic shaping or limiting so that each user gets 8 Mbit and then everyone else doesn't have to get terrible service due to the jerk (or jerks) that's torrenting the heck out of your shared connection...

---

So, if you completely want to stick with hardware you have now, you'll probably need to use just one WAN, and otherwise follow the above - set the other devices up as access points only. You should save enough on WAN charges to buy a machine to run a dual-WAN capable router on in a few months, and then you can go back to that, or not.

Comment: Thanks for being so thorough! Noticed you said that the other routers need to be connected via their LAN port - is there no way to set up those routers as *wireless* repeaters and have them still be a part of the same network? Also, can I assume from your response that some sort of complex routing rules set up per device (sending 6 to one router+dsl and 6 to another) isn't actually feasible?

Comment: WDS/Wireless uplink may be possible, depending on equipment and what software/firmware the equipment will run. It's **vastly inferior** to connecting them via wire, however, particularly since you are trying to serve up 200 Mbit of download. WDS cuts your potential throughput by at least half. It's entirely feasible to send 6 this way and 6 that way - if you have one router that groks both WANs. The "with current equipment" restraint is rather limiting there, given that it's not very flexible/capable consumer-grade equipment.